# AWS Boto3: Code works in the IPython console but not in a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, boto3

I am trying to take notes while I am studying boto3 and I want to use Jupyter. The below code works in the interactive console but it fails with

*EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL:
"https://ec2.Central.amazonaws.com/"*

When I try it in Jupyter. I suspect that it is because of Jupyter not being able to find the config and credentials files but I am not sure, the message is not saying exactly that

```
import boto3
ec2=boto3.resource('ec2')
response = ec2.create_vpc(
    CidrBlock='10.0.0.0/16',
)

print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always provide your credentials to [resource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.resource) explicitly:

```
ec2=boto3.resource(
    'ec2',
    region_name='REGION_NAME',
    aws_access_key_id='AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
    aws_secret_access_key='AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this working I had to create a system variable that holds the path to the configure file. The solution suggested by @scangetti is not secure.